Drawing rotational mechanical system

I'm struggling on the arrows to be consistent around the circle. Can anyone please help me on this one to be organize just like in the picture. Here is my example code.
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, positioning, arrows.meta, patterns.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) circle (1.5cm);
    \draw[xshift=0.2cm, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}, red] (.75,2) to[bend left=30] node[above=.25, font=\footnotesize] {\(\theta(t)\)} +(1,-1);
    \draw[xshift=0.2cm, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}, teal] (.75,1.5) to[bend left=30] node[above=.1, font=\footnotesize] {\(T\)} +(.75,-1);
    \draw[xshift=0.2cm, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}, teal] (1,-1.25) to[bend right=30] node[right=.1] {\footnotesize$D\frac{d\theta}{dt}$} +(.5,1.30);
    \draw[xshift=0.2cm, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}, teal] (-.6,-1.7) to[bend right=30] node[below=.1] {\footnotesize$K\theta$} +(1.3,.2);
    \draw[xshift=0.2cm, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}, teal] (-1.9,0) to[bend right=30] node[left=.1] {\footnotesize$J\frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}$} +(.9,-1.6);
    \node at (0,0) {\Huge$J$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


and the tag circuitikz is here because.... ? ;-)

Welcome to TeX.SX!

Here is a macro to make things a bit easier. The command is
\myarc[tikz commands]{center}{radius}{start angle}{end angle}{label}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, calc}

% [#1=tikz commands], #2=center, #3=radius, #4=start, #5=end, #6=label
\newcommand{\myarc}[6][]{
    \draw[#1, ->] ([shift=(#4:#3)]#2)arc(#4:#5:#3); 
    \node[label={[label distance={-2mm}, #1]{(#4+#5)/2}:{\footnotesize $#6$}}] at ($({(#4+#5)/2}:#3cm)+(#2)$){};
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>={Triangle[width=2pt]}]
\node[draw, circle, minimum size=3cm] at (0,0) (J) {\Huge $J$};
\myarc[teal, thick]{J}{1.75}{60}{15}{T}
\myarc[red, thick]{J}{2.4}{60}{15}{\theta_2}
\myarc[red, thick]{J}{1.75}{10}{-15}{9\theta_1}
\myarc[red, thick]{J}{1.75}{-20}{-60}{\frac{\mathrm{d}\theta_1}{\mathrm{d}t}}
\myarc[red, thick]{J}{1.75}{-120}{-65}{3\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\theta_2}{\mathrm{d}t^2}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Use
\draw (\sa:\r) arc[start angle=\sa, end angle=\ea, radius=\r];

Where \sa is the start angle, \ea is the end angle and \r is the radius for your arrows. Like this:
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\footnotesize]
\draw (0,0) circle[radius=1.5];
\draw[red, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}] (65:2.5) arc[start angle=65, end angle=25, radius=2.5] node[pos=0.5, above=1pt]{\(\theta(t)\)};
\draw[teal, -{Triangle[width=2pt]}] (55:1.8) arc[start angle=55, end angle=15, radius=1.8] node[pos=0.5, above=2pt]{\(T\)};
\node[font=\Huge] at (0,0) {\(J\)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


